# How to get the mysql connection for mysql-session (not the Sequelize instance)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, express, sequelize.js

I already have the Sequelize instance, but I need to get the mysql connection for mysql-session.

This is how the Sequelize instance looks like:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize( 'db_name', 'root', '',
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            idle: 10000
       }
    }
);

module.exports = sequelize;
```

I use Passport.js for the authentication system, but as database, I use mysql. Therefore, I am working with Sequelize module.

I want to do something like this:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(options);
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}/* session store options */, connection);
```

But since I use Sequelize, I do *not* want to use the `mysql.createConnection` method but to get the db connection object from the `sequelize` object (instance of `Sequelize`).

How to get the `mysql` connection for `express-mysql-session` (not the Sequelize instance)?

Comment: If I am not wrong this is same problem https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5731 ?

Comment: @tousifNoor Um, I think that's different––they are talking about different connections. The OP asks about one single connection which works via Sequelize, but the raw `mysql` (provided by the `mysql`) connection is needed.

Comment: how about `sequelize.connectionManager.getConnection().then(connection => { console.log(connection.connection) });`, where `sequelize` is a Sequelize instance.